# Added horizontal recycler view inside the vertical recyclerview issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am facing an issue while adding the horizontal recyclerview inside vertical recyclerview in 2nd position of recyclerview. The data is loaded in vertical recyclerview using arraylist. But the 2nd position data is not getting displayed in vertical recycler view in third position.How to achieve that?

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mWaveLineResponseList != null && mWaveLineResponseList.size() > 0) {
        return mWaveLineResponseList.size();
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 2) {
        viewPosition = 3;

    } else {
        viewPosition = (position == mWaveLineResponseList.size() - 1 && isLoadingAdded) ? VIEW_TYPE_PROGRESS : VIEW_TYPE_NORMAL;
    }
    return viewPosition;
}
```

Comment: I increased the arraylist size by adding                 mWaveLineResponseList.add(position,null); in oncreate view.Now it works fine.